# Determine contiguous dates in SQL gaps and islands

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, date-range, gaps-and-islands

I have a situation where a single patient can receive multiple services.  These services can have overlapping dates, and can gaps and islands.  I am trying to write a query that will show the contiguous length of time that the patient was receiving some kind of service.

Table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE #tt
(Patient    VARCHAR(10), StartDate DATETIME, EndDate DATETIME)
INSERT INTO #tt
VALUES
('Smith',   '2014-04-13',   '2014-06-04'),
('Smith',   '2014-05-07',   '2014-05-08'),
('Smith',   '2014-06-21',   '2014-09-19'),
('Smith',   '2014-08-27',   '2014-08-27'),
('Smith',   '2014-08-28',   '2014-09-19'),
('Smith',   '2014-10-30',   '2014-12-16'),
('Smith',   '2015-05-21',   '2015-07-03'),
('Smith',   '2015-05-22',   '2015-07-03'),
('Smith',   '2015-05-26',   '2015-11-30'),
('Smith',   '2015-06-25',   '2016-06-08'),
('Smith',   '2015-07-22',   '2015-10-22'),
('Smith',   '2016-08-11',   '2016-09-02'),
('Smith',   '2017-06-02',   '2050-01-01'),
('Smith',   '2017-12-22',   '2017-12-22'),
('Smith',   '2018-03-25',   '2018-06-30')
```

As you can see, many of the dates overlap.  Ultimately what I want to see is the following results, which will show the dates where the patient was receiving at least one service, like so:

```
Patient     |StartDate        |EndDate
--------------------------------------
Smith       |2014-04-13       |2016-06-04
Smith       |2014-06-21       |2014-09-19
Smith       |2014-10-30       |2014-12-16
Smith       |2015-05-21       |2016-06-08
Smith       |2016-08-11       |2016-09-02
Smith       |2017-06-02       |2050-01-01
```

I've gotten bleary eyed from looking at the various gaps and islands SQL code.  I've started out with this CTE, but obviously it isn't working, and if I wanted this, I could have simply used SELECT PHN, Min(StartDate), MAX(EndDate)

```
WITH HCC_PAT 
AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
    PHN,
    StartDate,
    EndDate,
    MIN (StartDate) OVER (  PARTITION BY  PHN ORDER BY StartDate
                                        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS PreviousStartDate,
    MAX (EndDate) OVER (    PARTITION BY  PHN ORDER BY EndDate
                                        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS PreviousEndDate 

FROM    #tt)

SELECT  DISTINCT --hcc_Pat.HCCClientKey,
        hcc_pat.PHN,
        hcc_pat.StartDate,
        ISNULL (LEAD (PreviousEndDate) OVER (PARTITION BY PHN ORDER BY ENDDATE), 'January 1, 2050') AS EndDate
FROM    HCC_PAT
WHERE   PreviousEndDate > StartDate 
AND     (StartDate < PreviousStartDate OR PreviousStartDate IS NULL)
```

Any help at this point would be gratefully appreciated

Comment: FWIW, your original attempt looks something like this, but was missing some steps to make it work. The key is to identify the "IslandStarts" and then count them to grant every record a unique ID. Otherwise, you're right the window functions don't add anything over a simple min/max aggregation. https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/sql-classic-problem-identifying-gaps-and-islands-across-overlapping-date-ranges-5681b5fcdb8

Answer (score 4):

One method spreads the dates out, with an indicator of whether the service is starting or ending.  Then a cumulative sum of the indicator can be used to define the different groups -- the zero values in the cumulative sum are when a period ends.

The final step is aggregation:

```
with d as (
      select patient, startdate as dte, 1 as inc from tt
      union all
      select patient, enddate as dte, -1 as inc from tt
     ),
     dd as (
       select patient, dte, sum(sum(inc)) over (order by dte) as cume_inc
       from d
       group by patient, dte
      ),
     ddd as (
       select dd.*, sum(case when cume_inc = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by patient order by dte desc) as grp
       from dd
      )
select patient, min(dte) as startdate, max(dte) as enddate
from ddd
group by grp;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bafa0c/13) is a SQL Fiddle.