# Repair historical data

Tags: sql-server

I have a historical table like this:

```
+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+
| valid_from       | valid_to         |  Profit | ID    |
+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+
| 20.05.2019 00:02 | 22.05.2019 23:42 |      10 | 12345 |
| 22.05.2019 23:42 | 28.05.2019 13:11 |      10 | 12345 |
| 28.05.2019 13:11 | 28.05.2019 23:59 |      10 | 12345 |
| 28.05.2019 23:59 | 29.05.2019 06:48 |     123 | 12345 |
| 29.05.2019 06:48 | 29.05.2019 13:21 |     123 | 12345 |
| 29.05.2019 13:21 | 29.05.2019 23:59 |     123 | 12345 |
| 29.05.2019 23:59 | 30.05.2019 06:39 |      10 | 12345 |
| 30.05.2019 06:39 | 30.05.2019 12:37 |     123 | 12345 |
| 30.05.2019 12:37 | 31.05.2019 00:09 |     123 | 12345 |
| 31.05.2019 00:09 | 31.05.2019 08:41 |     145 | 12345 |
| 31.05.2019 08:41 | 01.06.2019 00:22 |     145 | 12345 |
+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+
```

I deleted some columns. Row 1, 2 and 3 can now be summarized.

At first I tried following GROUP-BY Statement:

```
SELECT MIN(valid_from   ) AS valid_from 
      ,MAX(valid_to ) AS valid_to   
      ,Profit
      ,ID
INTO [repaired_archiv]
FROM temp.[wrong_archiv]
GROUP BY Profit
        ,ID
```

The result is:

```
+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+
| valid_from       | valid_to         |  Profit | ID    |
+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+
| 20.05.2019 00:02 | 30.05.2019 06:39 |      10 | 12345 |
| 28.05.2019 23:59 | 31.05.2019 00:09 |     123 | 12345 |
| 31.05.2019 00:09 | 01.06.2019 00:22 |     145 | 12345 |
+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+
```

but as you see, the valid_to column in the first row ist wrong. The reason for this is the wrong GROUP-BY Statement. I don't know how to get my aspected result like this:

```
+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+
| valid_from       | valid_to         |  Profit | ID    |
+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+
| 20.05.2019 00:02 | 28.05.2019 23:59 |      10 | 12345 |
| 28.05.2019 23:59 | 29.05.2019 23:59 |     123 | 12345 |
| 29.05.2019 23:59 | 30.05.2019 06:39 |      10 | 12345 |
| 30.05.2019 06:39 | 31.05.2019 00:09 |     123 | 12345 |
| 31.05.2019 00:09 | 01.06.2019 00:22 |     145 | 12345 |
+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Why are you storing datetime values as strings? The sample here is not valid as a datetime.

Comment: Looks like a gaps and island problem. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51049303/determine-contiguous-dates-in-sql-gaps-and-islands ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two `row_number()` :

```
select min(valid_from) as valid_from, max(valid_to) as valid_to, id, profit
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (order by valid_from) as seq1,
             row_number() over (partition by id, profit order by valid_from) as seq2
      from temp.[wrong_archiv] t
     ) t
group by id, profit, (seq1 - seq2)
order by valid_from;
```