# Combine overlapping date ranges for total medication days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find the date ranges that people were on medication. Unfortunately (for me), people do not wait till they are out to get a refill, so I need to add the number of days and combine any overlapping date ranges.

I'm able to combine the first date range, but I am lost on how to combine them all without some crazy looping.

```
WITH TBL AS (
    SELECT '2023-01-01' AS DOS, 31 AS DAYS, 'A' PERSON
    UNION 
    SELECT '2023-03-01' AS DOS, 31 AS DAYS, 'A' PERSON
    UNION  
    SELECT '2023-04-01' AS DOS, 60 AS DAYS, 'A' PERSON
    UNION  
    SELECT '2023-05-10' AS DOS, 60 AS DAYS, 'A' PERSON
)

SELECT T1.DOS 
      ,SUM(T1.DAYS) TTL_DAYS
      ,T1.PERSON
      ,MAX(DATEADD(DAY, T2.DAYS, T2.DOS))
FROM TBL T1 
LEFT JOIN TBL T2 ON T1.PERSON = T2.PERSON AND T2.DOS BETWEEN T1.DOS AND DATEADD(DAY, T1.DAYS, T1.DOS)
GROUP BY T1.PERSON, T1.DOS
```

I would like to end up with all the days that overlap to be combined into one row. There are other DAYS besides 31 and 60 - I used these for a simplified example.

[image]

Unfortunately, this is a bit harder that the suggested solution ([Determine contiguous dates in SQL gaps and islands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51049303/determine-contiguous-dates-in-sql-gaps-and-islands?noredirect=1&lq=1)) - I need to add all the days of medication that overlap.

The final END DATE is not 2023-05-10 + 60 as other solutions I have tried, it would be 2023-03-01 + 31 + 60 + 60.

Comment: lptr solution as fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/NpycpiYt (using a "gaps and islands" approach)

Comment: Thanks, @lptr - that's a bit closer but I need to add all the overlapping days and add it to the first start date that overlaps so that the END would be 2023-08-29 and not 2023-056 (5/10 + 60).

Comment: @PaulMaxwell - that's close but I need to all the medication days together and add them to the initial Start Date for the contiguous date range for the End Date.

Comment: @lptr - I thought it was working but it's not correct for some groups when I have more data. [https://dbfiddle.uk/-zawbZ2Y](https://dbfiddle.uk/-zawbZ2Y)

Comment: @lptr - when there's more data, it wasn't correct. [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-zawbZ2Y)