# Contiguous Gaps and Islands with Integers and Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, common-table-expression, gaps-and-islands

I have a table as below, with UserId, DayId, and Start/End Periods.  I need to simplify the data into this table into a view that combines overlapping and "adjacent" time period ranges, all grouped by UserId and Day.  I mention that it needs to be a view as it can't use code that a view doesn't support (e.g. a cursor).

(Edited to add additional input data and expected output. Any and all kinds of overlap are possible).

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable
(
    [UserId] INT,
    [DayId] INT,
    [StartTimePeriodId] INT,
    [EndTimePeriodId] INT
);

INSERT INTO #temptable
(
    [UserId],
    [DayId],
    [StartTimePeriodId],
    [EndTimePeriodId]
)
VALUES
(1001, 3, 9, 12),
(1001, 3, 11, 24),
(1001, 3, 37, 48),
(1001, 3, 39, 42),
(1001, 6, 11, 24),
(1001, 6, 25, 36),
(1001, 6, 37, 48),
(2002, 0, 11, 24),
(2002, 0, 25, 36),
(2002, 0, 37, 48),
(2002, 1, 11, 24),
(2002, 1, 25, 36),
(2002, 1, 37, 48),
(3003, 3, 1, 50),
(3003, 3, 11, 24),
(3003, 3, 37, 48),
(3003, 3, 39, 42),
(3003, 6, 11, 24),
(3003, 6, 25, 36),
(3003, 6, 37, 48)
```

Output for the view with the above data would look like:

| UserId | DayId | StartTimePeriodId | EndTimePeriodId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 3 | 9 | 24 |
| 1001 | 3 | 37 | 48 |
| 1001 | 6 | 11 | 48 |
| 2002 | 0 | 11 | 48 |
| 2002 | 1 | 11 | 48 |
| 3003 | 3 | 1 | 50 |
| 3003 | 6 | 11 | 48 |

Hopefully the sample data and output is enough for this question to make sense.  Let me know if there is anything I can clarify.

Edit: adding my last attempt before posting this question.  It was a CTE-based solution based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51050376/151084

```
;WITH d
AS (SELECT UserId,
           DayId,
           StartTimePeriodId TimePeriodId,
           1 AS IsStartPeriod
    FROM #temptable    
    UNION ALL
    SELECT UserId,
           DayId,
           EndTimePeriodId AS dte,
           -1 AS IsStartPeriod
    FROM #temptable    
    ),
     dd
AS (SELECT UserId,
           DayId,
           TimePeriodId,
           SUM(SUM(IsStartPeriod)) OVER (ORDER BY UserId, DayId, TimePeriodId) AS cume_inc
    FROM d
    GROUP BY UserId,
             DayId,
             TimePeriodId),
     ddd
AS (SELECT dd.UserId,
           dd.DayId,
           dd.TimePeriodId,
           dd.cume_inc,
           SUM(   CASE
                      WHEN cume_inc = 0 THEN
                          1
                      ELSE
                          0
                  END
              ) OVER (PARTITION BY UserId, DayId ORDER BY TimePeriodId DESC) AS grp
    FROM dd)
SELECT UserId,
       DayId,
       MIN(TimePeriodId) AS StartPeriod,
       MAX(TimePeriodId) AS EndPeriod
FROM ddd
GROUP BY UserId,
         DayId,
         grp
ORDER BY ddd.UserId,
         ddd.DayId,
         StartPeriod;
```

I don't *completely* understand the source query, so I wasn't not able to adapt it to what I need.

The results of the above query give me:

| UserId | DayId | StartPeriod | EndPeriod |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 3 | 9 | 24 |
| 1001 | 3 | 37 | 48 |
| 1001 | 6 | 11 | 24 |
| 1001 | 6 | 25 | 36 |
| 1001 | 6 | 37 | 48 |
| 2002 | 0 | 11 | 24 |
| 2002 | 0 | 25 | 36 |
| 2002 | 0 | 37 | 48 |
| 2002 | 1 | 11 | 24 |
| 2002 | 1 | 25 | 36 |
| 2002 | 1 | 37 | 48 |
| 3003 | 3 | 1 | 50 |
| 3003 | 6 | 11 | 24 |
| 3003 | 6 | 25 | 36 |
| 3003 | 6 | 37 | 48 |

It seems to handle overlaps, but not contiguous rows. E.g. EndTimePeriod of one row is 24 and StartTimePeriod of next row is 25, like UserId 2002 DayId 0.

Comment: Have you even tried anything? Perhaps using lead or lag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard gaps and islands technique would rely on creating a chain on consecutive of start-end periods and looking for the breaks. With the potential for long periods that span multiple smaller periods which themselves don't overlap causes a tiny snag. One solution to that is to eliminate as many redundant periods as possible in the first place. A period that fits entirely within another one can simply be ignored because it won't effect the outcome. Otherwise this uses the typical method of grouping by assigning a number deriving from the tally of times there's a gap between the time periods and aggregating based on that:

```
with filtered as (
    select *
    from T t1
    where not exists (
        select 1 from T t2
        where t2.UserId = t1.UserId and t2.DayId = t1.DayId
            and t2.StartTimePeriodId < t1.StartTimePeriodId
            and t2.EndTimePeriodId > t1.EndTimePeriodId
    )
), data as (
    select *,
        case when StartTimePeriodId - 1 <=
                  lag(EndTimePeriodId) over (
                      partition by UserId, DayId
                      order by StartTimePeriodId, EndTimePeriodId) then 0
             else 1 end as flag
    from filtered
), grp as (
    select *,
        sum(flag) over (
            partition by UserId, DayId
            order by StartTimePeriodId, EndTimePeriodId) as grp
    from data
)
select UserId, DayId,
    min(StartTimePeriodId) as StartPeriod, max(EndTimePeriodId) as EndPeriod
from grp
group by UserId, DayId, grp
order by UserId, DayId;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/zDh2Pv_X?hide=2

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be a standard gaps and island problem, one solution i go for is:

```sql
-- 3. Final grouping
SELECT  userId, DayId, min(starttimeperiodid), max(endtimeperiodid)
FROM    (
    SELECT  *
    -- 2. Agg group
    ,   SUM(flag) OVER(partition BY UserId, DayId ORDER BY StartTimePeriodId range BETWEEN unbounded preceding AND CURRENT row) AS groups
    FROM    (
        SELECT  *
        -- 1. Flag
        ,   CASE WHEN lag(EndTimePeriodId) OVER(partition BY UserId, DayId ORDER BY StartTimePeriodId) >= StartTimePeriodId - 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS flag
        FROM    #temptable
        ) x
    ) x 
GROUP BY userId, DayId, groups
```

Gaps is logically done by following 3 steps:

1. Flag: generates a flag 1 or 0 which compares previous value with current value to see if your desired condition changes. In this case, we want change if previous end period differs from current period
2. Agg group: Summarize the flags which creates the groups of islands that we're looking for and creates a grouping field.
3. Final grouping: gather the results grouped by the grouping field

This won't work if you have very overlapping things that cross multiple groups boundaries, but if they don't, then you're good to go.

Comment: "This won't work if you have very overlapping things that cross multiple groups boundaries, but if they don't, then you're good to go."
I think this is possible.  I'll find out and update the question if so, and accept the answer if not.